# How can I change this the object property assignment to avoid prototype pollution

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, security, prototype

I have a line of code that looks like

```
  gMapping[userName] = gMapping[userName] || [];
```

I see Prototype pollution vulnerability raised by Snyk. How can this be resolved ?

**Relevant code:**

```
const gMapping: { [user_name: string]: string[] } = {};

// Map records to dictionaries
dbRecs.forEach(rec => {
    const userName = rec.user_name;
    const groupId = rec.group_id;
    gMapping[userName] = gMapping[userName] || [];
    gMapping[userName].push(groupId);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `glMapping`? Where does `userName` come from? Can you be more specific about the Snyk warning message?

Comment: @Bergi : userName comes from the DB. added the details about gMapping in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `userName` could be [`"__proto__"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). I'm not certain this would be exploitable in your case, but it still causes an exception when trying to invoke `.push()` on `Object.prototype`.

To [avoid this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57780961/1048572), either use `Object.create(null)` (which [isn't easy with TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1108), unfortunately) or switch to a proper ES6 `Map<string, string[]>`.

Comment: Okay, so if we change const gMapping: { [user_name: string]: string[] } = {}; to a map instead of an object, it would be okay, Is that correct?

Comment: @SKhurana yes .